# Make the integral symbol bigger

Tags: math-mode, equations, delimiters, integral

How can I make the integral symbol bigger independent of the rest of equation? The symbol appears with the same size of a delimiter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.